# Plotting a table of log-log values

Tags: python, plot

I have a table of values which aren't logs but to find their relation I think I need to create a log-log plot. The values I have are:

```
R     C
----------
0.2   103
2     13.9
20    2.72
200   0.800
2000  0.401
20000 0.433
```

How do I plot the logs of these values ?

Comment: yh ok ive had a look but im not really confident with using it

Comment: Well, I can't make you confident, only you can do that.  Either look at matplotlib examples and learn, or just use excel.  This doesn't necessarily require a programming solution, even if some among us (myself included) often use any excuse to load up the Python interpreter.

Comment: yes I know that but I have a interpolation problem which I am setting up for and on the confidence thing I think I am getting there

Comment: ive started my code with import numpy.log and despite this when I run my code I am being told there is no module called log

Comment: You just need to `import numpy` and then you can access `numpy.log()` but since the default math library already has a log function, I wouldn't mess with numpy if you're just getting started.